# Raising exception within setter

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have class that has a property. Within this property I am trying to validate that the datatable is not null.  If it is null then it generates an exception.

The question that I have is how to capture that in the calling class if I want to display the error message within a label control for example.

Here is the property:

```
    public DataTable DtNotes
    {
        get
        {
            return _dtNotes;
        }
        set
        {
            _dtNotes = value;
            if (_dtNotes != null)
            {
                _dtNotes.Columns.Remove("id");
                _dtNotes.DefaultView.Sort = "note_type ASC";
                _dtNotes.AcceptChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", "Null Datable");
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using this within an asp.net application.

Comment: Aside: Note the existence of `class ArgumentNullException`

Comment: I hope you're rethrowing any `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exceptions that you catch...

Comment: @MatthewWatson -- Why would he want to do that?  His only requirement is that it display a message when the exception occurs.  Re-throwing doesn't sound like a desirable outcome here.

Comment: Typically you should not pass exception messages to the UI as it may expose internal app info, and possible vulnerabilities. If you are going to use exceptions as a means for conveying errors to the user, consider creating a custom exception type within your application for that purpose.

Comment: Also consider what may happen if you pass in a `DataTable` that does _not_ have a column named "id".

Comment: @rory.ap You shouldn't be in the position of swallowing exceptions like ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: @MatthewWatson -- It depends.  If you don't want the exception to bubble all the way up, then yes you do want to swallow it.  For example, if you have an MS Office add-in built in .NET and you let an exception bubble up without catching it, it will wreak havoc on other add-ins (bad design, sure).  Another example is a windows service.  If you have a framework for dealing with exceptions in a manner that's appropriate, then you want to deal with it and swallow.  Who are you insinuating should handle the exception?

Comment: @MatthewWatson -- And you're assuming that the OP's message displaying the error details is not a UI/front-end for some exception framework or code testing apparatus.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `try-catch` block in the calling class and display your message in the catch block:

```
try
{
    // use DtNotes here, throws an ex.
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
{
    // display message here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
try { 
   myClass.DtNotes = null; //Null assignment throws exception
} catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex){ //Catch the exception
   string message = ex.Message; //Retrieve the message
   //You can display the message here
}
```